# C# How use sign from another window?

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a problem with use one textBox in two Forms.
I have string s = TextBox1.Text with Form1
and i need use this s on another Form2?
How make it?

Hmy that public static string dont worked...
I have:
        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            public static string s = textBox1.Text;
        }
This is not worked, i need use this "s" in another metod with another window :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it as a public static property on `Form1` and then you can access it from where ever.

```
//in form1
public static string s;

//in form2
TextBox.Text = Form1.s;
```

Comment: Hmy that is not work.
I have:

Comment: @user2323554 no, it works. Make sure Form1 is a `public class` and not just a class (defaults to private so Form2 won't be able to access it).

Comment: First of all - s is a field, not a property. Public fields are bad.
Second, this proposal adds an unnecessary dependency in Form2 on Form1. One way around could be a (third) static configuration class.

Answer (score 0):

Have a public method in Form2: SetText(String s) (or alike), that sets the TextBox in Form2 from From1.